# Laravel 5 return column values in one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am working in a one to many relationship where the user model has many in the asset model.  I am trying to create a method where if the name of an asset already exist for the user in the DB name column it can't be uploaded again.

```
$assets = Auth::user()->assets;
```

this ^ returns the two asset rows i have in the assets db.

```
[{"id":18,"user_id":2,"name":"bootstrap.css","size":"153790","extension":"css","url":"\/\/cdn.aircss.io\/testing1\/bootstrap.css","subdirectory":"","created_at":"2015-05-26 05:21:59","updated_at":"2015-05-26 05:21:59"},{"id":19,"user_id":2,"name":"jquery.dynatable.js","size":"60347","extension":"js","url":"\/\/cdn.aircss.io\/testing1\/jquery.dynatable.js","subdirectory":"","created_at":"2015-05-26 05:22:12","updated_at":"2015-05-26 05:22:12"}]1
```

I just want to display the values in the name column so I can run my if statement of

```
if($assets == $filename)
        {
            return redirect('upload')->with('errornotice', 'A file with that name already exist');
        }
```

Comment: What are the return value of $assets for you ?

Comment: Can't you use if(in_array($assets, $filename)) in your if statesment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  My asset variable needed to be

```
$assets = Auth::user()->assets->first()->name;
```

In my case they only will ever have one of each file name.

Comment: Be sure to mark your own answer as the correct one so people don't keep coming here to answer a question which had already been answered :)